# Why Geofence tracking using Cllocationmanager delegate methods not calling

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

Hiii,

I implemented Geo fences by using location manager.

Here  i am creating regions

enter code here

In view did load i create object as

//for Geo fence tracking

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setDelegate:self];
 locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

-(void)TraceGeofenceLocation{
    for (int k=0; k< [self.chGeofenceType count]; k++) {
    NSString *chTracLati = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[self.chGeofenceLatitudes objectAtIndex:k] doubleValue]];
    NSString *chTracLong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[self.chGeofeceLongitudes objectAtIndex:k] doubleValue]];
    NSString *chTracRadius = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[self.chGeofenceRadius objectAtIndex:k] doubleValue]];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(chTracLati.doubleValue, chTracLong.doubleValue);



        if ([[self.chGeofenceType objectAtIndex:k] intValue] == 1) {

                region = [[CLRegion alloc]initCircularRegionWithCenter:coord radius:chTracRadius.doubleValue identifier:@"Restricted"];
            }
            else if ([[self.chGeofenceType objectAtIndex:k] intValue] == 2){

                region = [[CLRegion alloc]initCircularRegionWithCenter:coord radius:chTracRadius.doubleValue identifier:@"SafeZone"];
            }
            else{
                region = [[CLRegion alloc]initCircularRegionWithCenter:coord radius:chTracRadius.doubleValue identifier:@"Curfew"];

            }
            [region setNotifyOnEntry:YES];
            [region setNotifyOnExit:YES];

            [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region desiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

        }

    }
```

I tested in my delegate methods if any region it will enter or not.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    locationnew = locations.lastObject;
    self.Latit=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", locationnew.coordinate.latitude];
    self.Longi=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",locationnew.coordinate.longitude];
    Speed = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[locationnew speed]] floatValue];

    NSLog(@"Speed :%f Latitude :%@ Longitude :%@",Speed,self.Latit,self.Longi);
```

}

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{

    if ([region.identifier isEqualToString:@"Restricted"]) {

        [self sendNotificationtoServerwithtype:@"1"];
    }

    else  if ([region.identifier isEqualToString:@"Curfew"]){

        [self sendNotificationtoServerwithtype:@"3"];
    }

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

       if ([region.identifier isEqualToString:@"SafeZone"]){

        [self sendNotificationtoServerwithtype:@"2"];
    }

}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    if (state == CLRegionStateInside){
        NSLog(@"is in target region");

    }else{
        NSLog(@"is out of target region");
    }

}
```

My delegate method update locations are calling and i get in console,
but enter into region,exit from regions and did DetermineState  are not calling...

Can anybody help me please.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

*startUpdatingLocation* and *startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges* are mutually exclusive. If you want to do *startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges* to look for geofences, make sure you call *stopUpdatingLocation* first.

Also be aware that geofence detection is not incredibly precise. On average, you can a resolution of hundreds of meters. I've found that *didEnterRegion* often take several minutes to be called, if at all.

NOTE: you are currently calling [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region desiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest]; The problem with this is kCLLocationAccuracyBest is a really small area. (kCLLocationAccuracyBest codes for the value 1.0). That means you are asking the system to let you know when you enter an area with a diameter 1.0 meter. Since geofence detection has accuracy of hundreds of meters, this may never get called. Instead you should set the accuracy to something much lower: [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region desiredAccuracy:**200.0**];

Good luck.